# A friend at hand - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> What force and strength cannot get through
>   I with a gentle touch can do;
>   And many in the streets would stand,
>   Were I not, as friend, at hand.

An old-classic 
From The Book of Riddle -
Portland: Bailey & Noyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a:

> Key.

What force and strength cannot get through I with a gentle touch can do;

> Opens doors.

And many in the streets would stand, Were I not, as a friend, at hand.

> No one could get into their houses without a key (without brute force) if keys were not a friend literally at hand.

Comment: That was quick... nice one @Duck

Comment: Thanks, seems like all of the puzzles you post I've heard somewhere.

Comment: It seems so obviously :D I got another posted tho